# Greater than and less than or equal to in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I use greater than equal to and less than equal to instead of using `between` in SQL?

I'm checking for date variable in SQL.

I tried like this:

```
Date between coalesce(@fromDate,Date) and coalesce(@toDate,Date)
```

but if user does not enter any of date (fromDate or toDate)

so that I need to convert above condition in "greater than equal to and less than equal to".

How can I write this syntax in SQL?

Comment: @christiandev Why is `ISNULL()` better option than `COALESCE()`?

Comment: @christiandev `Coalesce()` will be perfectly adequate when only checking a single value. Why bother swapping to a non-standard function in those instances?

Comment: @gvee, OK, I will retract the comment - I always thought there was a perf impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF @fromDate IS NULL
  BEGIN
    SET @fromDate = '1900-01-01';
  END;

IF @toDate IS NULL
  BEGIN
    SET @toDate = '2099-01-01';
  END;

SELECT things
FROM   table
WHERE  date_field BETWEEN @toDate AND @fromDate;
```

This code will essentially give you an arbitrarily large range to check which *should* give you reasonable performance and return all results (assuming that's what you want when neither value is supplied).

This code can be shortened to:

```
SELECT things
FROM   table
WHERE  date_field BETWEEN Coalesce(@toDate, '1900-01-01') AND Coalesce(@fromDate, '2099-01-01');
```

But I kept the verbose version to illustrate.

Comment: He wants to convert condition in greater than equal to and less than equal. He already tried `Between`

Comment: `val >= x AND val <= y` is equivalent to `val BETWEEN x AND y`. @Ajay

Comment: I know that but he wants `>= and <=` not `BETWEEN x AND y`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Date FROM TableName WHERE Date > @fromDate AND Date < @toDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Account AS a
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND (
        @toDate IS NULL
        OR a.CreateDate <= @toDate
    )
    AND (
        @fromDate IS NULL
        OR a.CreateDate >= @fromDate
    )
```

Please note the 1 = 1 is only there to make the conditions clear and is by no means needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what the where clause would look like.

```
Where
 Date >= @fromDate
And
 Date <= @toDate
```